# comparing two strings of EditTexts in android

Tags: java, android

I am sorry if this is a silly question but i tried to find the answer but couldn't get.
plse help me..
i am new in android studio but have basic java knowledge.
Actually, the problem is i am trying to compare value of `TextView` and `EditText` like this;

```
TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2);

String x = a.getText().toString();
String y = b.getText().toString();

if(x==y)
{
//----stuff--;
}
```

Doesn't show any error but the code under 'if' don't execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: there is nothing special about Android Studio since code won't run in it. It is the same for all IDEs. Mention `Android Studio` only if you face any issues with IDE.

Comment: in your case X == Y will be true if both strings are same. eg "Dog" == "Dog"  but case sensitive can return it as false eg "Dog" == "dog"

Comment: @CharukaSilva, only if it’s the same string object. It will be false for two identical string objects (which I suspect the OP is facing). Follow the link to the question that we think this one is a duplicate of for explanation.

Comment: @Ole V.V. yes.Good point. so regarding to this question x= a.getText().toString() and y= b.getText().toString() they belongs to same String object or not? just asking to clear things in my head

Comment: If the user has entered one of them, that will usually create a new string object separately from the existing one. I f we wanted to be sure, we’d have to dig through a lot of code. Fortunately the right solution is in that other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y))
{
//----stuff--;
}
```

Follow this link to know more about it : 
http://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 1):

Use either `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` depending on case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare two strings with equal to operator.
Use equals or equalsIgnoreCase like below code.

```
if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
//return value true if both the strings are same.
}
```

Comment: your 'if' code works..but you said 2 strings can't be compare with equal to operator...i could compare 2 strings when i write like this: String x="wangz"; String y="wangz"; if(x==y); it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = a.getText().toString();
String y = b.getText().toString();
boolean correct = x.equals(y);
if(correct)
{
//do stuff
}
```

**use this**

Comment: thanks for help...but still didn't understand why if(x==y) didn't work... but i am sure to use x.equals(y) now onwards.

Comment: With == (for strings) in java you are comparing they are of same reference. Like you did is the test if both of them are strings objects.

Answer (score 0):

> The **==** operator tests whether two variables have the **same references
>   (identity) aka memory address**.
>
> Whereas the **equals()** method tests whether two variables refer to objects
>   that have the **same state (values)**.

I suggest you to use **equals()** method if no need to matching case if matching case than use **equalsIgnoreCase()**

like

```
if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
    //both string are equals
 }
```